# Reset column increment datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to update the row increment number in a `DataGridView` in my `WinForms` application after deleting a row or rows. I have looked at sources and the all point on how to add the incrementing to a column in `DataTable`.  My DataGridView is bound to my DataTable, and that is bound to a DataSet.

**How I created by datatable:**

```
DataColumn itemNumber = new DataColumn();
itemNumber.ColumnName = "ItemNumber";
itemNumber.AutoIncrement = true;
itemNumber.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
itemNumber.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

DataColumn article = new DataColumn();
article.ColumnName = "Article";
article.ReadOnly = true;

DataColumn description = new DataColumn();
description.ColumnName = "Description";
description.ReadOnly = true;

DataColumn type = new DataColumn();
type.ColumnName = "Type";
type.ReadOnly = true;

//add to datatable
dt.Columns.Add(itemNumber);
dt.Columns.Add(article);
dt.Columns.Add(description);
dt.Columns.Add(type);
```

**Removing a row from the DataGridView**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvView.SelectedRows)
{
    dgvView.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
}
```

If I have 5 rows, and delete one. I would like the increment values to start from the 1,2,3,4 etc...

Can someone point me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of an efficient way to do this, but here are some ideas that *may* work with small data sets.

### Keep up with the values yourself

1) Don't define the column as an AutoIncrement column):

```
DataColumn itemNumber = new DataColumn();
itemNumber.ColumnName = "ItemNumber";
//itemNumber.AutoIncrement = true;
//itemNumber.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
//itemNumber.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
```

2) Handle the `DataGridView.RowsAdded` and `DataGridView.RowsRemoved` events and "reset" the values:

```
private void dgvView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvView.Columns.Contains("ItemNumber"))
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvView.Rows)
        {
            r.Cells["ItemNumber"].Value = r.Index + 1;
        }
    }
}

private void dgvView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvView.Columns.Contains("ItemNumber"))
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvView.Rows)
        {
            r.Cells["ItemNumber"].Value = r.Index + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Regenerate the values by rebuilding the `DataTable` and rebinding to it

1) Define the helper method below:

```
private DataTable ResetAutoIncrementColumn(DataTable dt, string autoIncrementColumnName)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    DataColumn itemNumber = new DataColumn(autoIncrementColumnName);
    itemNumber.AutoIncrement = true;
    itemNumber.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
    itemNumber.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
    result.Columns.Add(itemNumber);

    dt.Columns.Remove(autoIncrementColumnName);
    result.Merge(dt, true);
    return result;
}
```

2) Call it at the appropriate time (e.g. after a series of deletes as in the original question):

```
dt = ResetAutoIncrementColumn(dt, "ItemNumber");
dt.Columns["ItemNumber"].SetOrdinal(0);
dgvView.DataSource = dt;
dgvView.Columns["ItemNumber"].DisplayIndex = 0;
```

---

### If you are just looking for a visual row number

Also, if you are just looking to have a visual row number on the `DataGridView` (and you don't care about the value being present in the underlying `DataTable`), you can handle the `DataGridView.RowPostPaint` event as follows (pulled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12840794/3085273):

```
private void dgGrid_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGridView;
    var rowIdx = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

    var centerFormat = new StringFormat() 
    { 
        // right alignment might actually make more sense for numbers
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, 
        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    };

    var headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I can see this is not an efficient. Seems like a lot of work just to set reset the increment values. But I think you are correct, for this work the incrementing should be handled by adding each row.Index +1. I will add the rowsAdded and rowsRemoved handler to this.