# DataTable/DataGridView Row Number Display

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I want to display in my first Column of my `DataGridView` but not found I a good solution. I try add a new Column to DGV but it crashed..

```
List<string[]> rows =  File.ReadAllLines(Open_CSV.FileName, 
                       Encoding.ASCII).Select(x => x.Split(';')).ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (string s in rows[0])
{
    dt.Columns.Add(s);
}
rows.RemoveAt(0);
rows.ForEach(x =>
{
    dt.Rows.Add(x);
});

DGV_DATA.DataSource = dt;
```

Do you have some solution where is the best place add in `DataTable` or `DataGridView`?

Comment: So to clarify: you want to show the row number in the first column of a DataGridView?

Comment: @sydan yes i want display the row number in first column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `DataSource`, manually adding data might cause problems, as you experienced. Adding a row-number to the `DataSource` is obviously not a good idea, as long as the number does not belong to the data. In this case, one idea would be to display the number in the row-header, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581626/show-row-number-in-row-header-of-a-datagridview).

In your case, where you building the DataSource by yourself, you might think of leaving the path of using the DataSource-Property and start adding the rows directly.
The `Rows`-Property of the `DataGridView` can be used to add rows by hand. You only would need to build something like a List of `DataGridViewRow`-objects, which you can pass to the `AddRange`-method. To these `DataGridViewRows` you could add the additional column. And be sure to add that additional column also to the `Columns`-Collection of the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is very efficient but this could do the trick

```
List<string[]> rows =  File.ReadAllLines(......)
                         .Select((x,i) => 
                         string.Join(";", (i+1).ToString(), x)
                         .Split(';')).ToList();
```

You could use the version of Select that use the indexer of the current item in the sequence and add that index to the string that will be splitted.
My concerns are relative to the fact that in this way you build an additional string but, you don't need to change anything in the following code.

Comment: should't it be `string.Join((i+1).ToString(), ";", x)`?

Comment: Uhm, no the first parameter of string.Join is the separator

Comment: Oh, OK. Did not try `Join` before ;)