# C# - Deserialize Json to Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, json

Im trying to convert my List code lines to Dictionary since as i understand they are faster, and more easy to manage, like i can get its value with its key value rather than just index.

Thus, im trying to modify my json-deserializing code (which actually,Newtonsoft's), but i have no idea how can i convert raw json to dictionary with my own format.

```
Dictionary <string,Tag>
```

Tag class is my own class with member variables, contains tag informations.
it doesnt includes functions for sure.

String should be Tag.Name, a string member variable.

```
            //TODO: Fix "Hacky" solution to deserialized lines into Dictionary
            //Which means : Raw Json -> Deserialized data -> List -> Dictionary is very hacky in my perspective
            //Should be : Raw Json -> Deserialized data -> Dictionary, but i have no idea to convert directly like that

            else if (filename.Contains(".json")) // very janky method to detect json file. dont depend on file extension - rather depend on actual file format.
            {
                string line = String.Join("", Lines);

                List<Tag> lv_list = new List<Tag>();
                Dictionary<string,Tag> lv_dict = new Dictionary<string, Tag>();

                lv_list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tag>>(line);

                gVar.Tags.AddRange(lv_list);
                gVar.gTagCount += lv_list.Count();

                for (int i = 0; i < lv_list.Count(); ++i)
                {
                    gVar.Tags2.Add(lv_list[i].Name, lv_list[i]);
                }

                int lv_tagcount = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < gVar.gTagCount; ++i)
                {
                    gVar.Tags[i].TagCount = lv_tagcount;
                    ++lv_tagcount;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother deserializing *directly* to a Dictionary: if the JSON is formatted like an array, go ahead and deserialize it to a List first. There's nothing "hacky" about the two-step process.

Use LINQ's `ToDictionary()` method to get a dictionary from a list:

```
Dictionary<string,Tag> lv_dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tag>>(line)
    .ToDictionary(tag => tag.Name);
```

You seem to have a habit of initializing a variable with an empty collection that never gets used, and then setting the variable to some other value. This isn't helpful: just declare and set the variable at the same time. But based on this pattern I'm wondering if `gVar` is an object you're trying to initialize even though your code looks like it's trying to *add* things to that variable. Do you really want to do something more like this?

```
gVar.Tags2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tag>>(line)
    .ToDictionary(tag => tag.Name);
```

I'd also question whether the `TagCount` property is a good pattern. It looks like you're trying to make each Tag explicitly aware of its own position in the collection that it's found in. This is a code smell. Perhaps now that you're using a Dictionary that won't be necessary because you can look up the tag by its name in the Dictionary?

Comment: TagCount member variable isnt for indexing like u said. i uses datagridview to display these List/Dictionary for users. i prefer to count their numbers and display them, thats why i record them like that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your specific situation, so I can't judge as well as you can, but it seems like putting a row number on the `Tag` class itself is putting responsibilities in the wrong places. Have you considered a strategy like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581709/120955) to have the DataGridView display the row number without it being a part of the model itself?