# DataGridView's row headers lose their captions on sort

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, datagridrowheader

I followed a tip in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710064/adding-text-to-datagridview-row-header) which said:

```
datagridview1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "ur text";
```

With help of this I set up a method:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e, DataSet src)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = row_captions[i];
    }
}
```

and it nicely fills all my rows' headers with captions. The problem occurs when I try to sort any column. This method is called again and the captions stay in the same order even tho the rows are arranged in a different way. I tried using a bool value so it wouldn't call this method again like this:

```
private first_time = true;

private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e, DataSet src)
{
    if(first_time)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = row_captions[i];
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    first_time = false;
}
```

However now, it won't add the captions at all, because apparently the rows are removed and added again and thus lose their properties (correct me if I am wrong, because I am not completely sure).

**Is there a way to both: maintain the captions of the rows and sort them accordingly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to set the `HeaderCell.Value` in the event `CellFormatting` and its sort accordingly

```
 private void dataGridView`_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = e.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The point is, I have row captions in array, not written on the datagrid cells itself, so I cannot fetch them from there. And when I try to get the captions from array, I cannot identify which row is which. Your example is working for me too, but again, you get the value from the value of the cell of the same row which I do not seem to be able to do, unless I somehow manage to hide that row, containing the row captions

Comment: So yeah I went this way: I added an invisible column which had all the captions and using your idea I rewrote your function like this (removed the if because it was really disturbing): `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[rows.Count].Value;`. Thanks!

Comment: that's great! you have really discovered a new trick today, always welcome :)