# Viewing Row number in GridView Control C#

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datagridview

I want to know if it possible to add a row number for each row in the GridView Control in the boxes as shown in the image.

[image]

Is this possible or not?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: i have googled it and all the examples i have found is adding a new column with the row number in it. I want the row number to be in the box the arrows are pointing in. So no i haven't tried anything because i wouldn't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in  dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[r.Index].HeaderCell.Value = (r.Index + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks man. this worked. i'll accept the answer as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710064/adding-text-to-datagridview-row-header)

```
datagridview1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "ur text";
```

Answer (score -1):

User `ROW_NUMBER()` function in your query:

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AdrId) as RNK
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: i know how to get the row numbers. my question is that if it possible to add the row number in the gridview as shown in the image

Comment: no u have misunderstood my question. And i am idicating where i want the row numbers to be. Read this again "I want to know if it possible to add a row number for each row **in the GridView Control in the boxes as shown in the image**."