# Sorting Inside datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having datagridview in c#

I populated data inside datagridview.

I created Serial No inside datagridview along with other columns.

If i click serial no head,the serial no is sorted.
If i do sorting  in other columns,the serial no is also sorted.

How to avoid sorting serial no, if I click other column headers.

I have given the code below

```
         dsstock = new DataSet();
        dsstock = fetchDataSetValues(statement);
      //  grdStock.Rows.Clear();
        if (dsstock.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grdStock.Columns.Add("Sl. No.", "Sl. No.");
            grdStock.Columns[0].Width = 80;

            grdStock.Columns.Add("ItemID", "Item ID");
            grdStock.Columns[1].Width =300;
            grdStock.Columns.Add("ItemName", "Item Name");
            grdStock.Columns[2].Width = 600;
            grdStock.Columns.Add("ItemQuantity", "Item Quantity");
            grdStock.Columns[3].Width = 150;
            int row = dsstock.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1;

            for (int r = 0; r <= row; r++)
            {
                grdStock.Rows.Add();
                grdStock.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value = r + 1;
                grdStock.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value = dsstock.Tables[0].Rows[r].ItemArray[0];
                grdStock.Rows[r].Cells[2].Value = dsstock.Tables[0].Rows[r].ItemArray[1];
                grdStock.Rows[r].Cells[3].Value = dsstock.Tables[0].Rows[r].ItemArray[2];

            }
        }
```

Thanks

Chandran

Comment: The serial no starts at 1 and counts until the number of items within your grid?! So instead of adding an increasing number which you do not want to be sorted, why don't you change the rowHeader Text? have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710064/adding-text-to-datagridview-row-header)

Comment: isn't that depends on "ORDER BY" in your SQL Select ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a way to keep the rows numbered the same regardless of which data is there (like Excel does). That seems odd to me if you are assigning a serial number to each item/row, but anyway there is a simple solution at [Show row number in row header of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581626/show-row-number-in-row-header-of-a-datagridview). (You can see a screenshot at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14915110/116891.)

```
private void dgGrid_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGridView;
    var rowIdx = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

    var centerFormat = new StringFormat() 
    { 
        // right alignment might actually make more sense for numbers
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, 
        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    };

    var headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
}
```