# How to call a hash algorithm in an ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I'm seeking for the possibility for hashing a password in an `ActionResult`.
To be specific, I want to call my SHA512 method in the public `ActionResult Edit(User user)` to hash the password if it got changed.

Here is the code of the `Edit` method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

I am actually new to ASP.NET and I really don't know how to call this method in order to hash the new password, if there is one:

```
    public static string SHA512(string value)
    {
        byte[] result;
        SHA512 sha512 = new SHA512Managed();
        result = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value));

        string hash = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", String.Empty); 

        return hash;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You update your models by first getting it from database and then calling TryUpdateModel on it. Then you add your new password hash for user (`u`) that is taken from database and save him.

Side note: Hashing passwords using SHA is very bad because algorithm is fast. Try using `PBKDF2` instead.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    var u = db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == user.Id);

    if (TryUpdateModel(u))
    {
        u.Password = SHA512(user.Password)
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve :)
What do you mean by saying Hashing passwords using SHA ist very bad because algorithm is fast?

Comment: @user2391883 You can computer hash very fast meaning if someone will steal your hash tables he will brute-force it very fast. Passwords algorithms must be slow so that brute-force attacks are pretty much useless since it takes forever. Also, if someone answers your question you better mark it as answered.

Comment: @user2391883 In my opinion Steve is not quite right here! SHA512 (even better a salted SHA512) is a really good possibility to secure your passwords. You may have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710064/adding-text-to-datagridview-row-header) which calculates 3,17 * 10^64 years necessary to crack a SHA512 hash with brute force. If I understood anything wrong Steve pls let me know!

Comment: @Steve I'm using the SHA512 Class from Microsoft. Later i will add a Salt to those hash values. I think it should be safe then :)
Once again thank you for your answer