# C# databinding in datagridview set the row header

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've found this [tutorial about binding a list to a DataGridView](http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection) which is quite nice. Let's consider the example from the tutorial:

[image]

I'd like to be able to put the brand (Ford/Sheldy AC/Chevrolet) in the row header automatically. How can I specify it? I've done a few try without any interesting result...

Comment: You need to dynamically create the columns, will work on giving an example

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710064/adding-text-to-datagridview-row-header

Comment: @DavidePiras I don't see anything about rows header **provided by** the binding list in here. Maybe the way my question was asked was not the best or I missed something in the list you provide... But to me, this is not a dup

Comment: @Thomas so in your case to manually change the property: HeaderCell.Value does not help?

Comment: @DavidePiras if I do that I'll have the brand name displayed two times, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently re installing everything on my pc so this is the best I could come up with:

```
private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<List<object>> list)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(MyList[i], typeof(string));
    }
    table.Columns.Add("", typeof(object));
    // Add rows data
    List<object[]> tObj = new List<object[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        tObj.Add((object[])(list[i].ToArray()));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(tObj[i]);
    }
    return table;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Well the goal of a binding list is to avoid this kind of manipulation...